# How to get substrings from an Xpath using C#?

Tags: c#, string, xpath, substring

I have an `Xpath` property inside of a JSON file and I'd like to get two substrings from this Xpath to assisting these substrings into two variables.

The JSON object is as follows;

```js
    {
        'selectGateway':'0',
        'waitingTime':'20000',
        'status':'200',
        'correlationID':'1',
        'matchString':[{'xpath':'/whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field[@key="whitelist-entry" and @value="8.0440147AA44A80"]','value':''}],
        'matchInteger':[],
        'matchSortedList':[]

    }
```

This is my attempt so far it's working properly, I'm just looking for a way to do this more dynamically and in a better way if it's possible.

```
int firstStringPositionForKey = matchString[index].xpath.IndexOf("@key=\"");
int secondStringPositionForKey = matchString[index].xpath.IndexOf("\" and");
string betweenStringForKey = matchString[index].xpath.Substring(firstStringPositionForKey+6, secondStringPositionForKey-firstStringPositionForKey-6);

int firstStringPositionForValue = matchString[index].xpath.IndexOf("@value=\"");
int secondStringPositionForValue = matchString[index].xpath.IndexOf("\"]");
string betweenStringForValue = matchString[index].xpath.Substring(firstStringPositionForValue+8, secondStringPositionForValue-firstStringPositionForValue-8);
```

I expect the output to be like:

```
key is : whitelist-entry
value is : 8.0440147AA44A80
```

Comment: What you tried so far? show us your attempts. Hint: you can use `Split('/').Last()`

Comment: I've added my attempt in main question, you may check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting value of xPath in `matchString[index].xpath`, so here is the solution

```
//Test is nothing but your xPath
string test = "/whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field[@key=\"whitelist-entry\" and @value=\"8.0440147AA44A80\"]";

//Split your string by '/' and get last element from it.
string lastElement = test.Split('/').LastOrDefault();

//Use regex to get text present in "<text>"
var matches = new Regex("\".*?\"").Matches(lastElement);

//Remove double quotes         
var key = matches[0].ToString().Trim('\"');
var @value = matches[1].ToString().Trim('\"');;

//Print key and value   
Console.WriteLine("Key is: ${key}");
Console.WriteLine("Value is: ${value}");
```

Output:

```
Key is: whitelist-entry
Value is: 8.0440147AA44A80
```

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UtlPAP)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped. Kindly accept answer so it will help others to read

Answer (score 0):

Using `Regex` ([Link to formula](https://regex101.com/r/ULAe3J/1))

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("your_json");
var xpath = ((JArray)obj["matchString"])[0]["xpath"].Value<string>();

string pattern = "(?<=key=\")(.*?)(?=\").*(?<=value=\")(.*?)(?=\")";
var match = new Regex(pattern).Match(xpath);

string key = match.Groups[1].Value;   
string value = match.Groups[2].Value;
```